# Azure SQL Hyperscale - 0 secondary replicas?

Tags: azure-sql-database, replication

**Backdrop**

I develop a forecasting engine (time series) for different purposes. Processing, modeling and forecasting modules are written in Python, and data is currently stored in an Azure SQL database. Currently the database is General Purpose (vCore-based) service tier, Provisioned compute tier and Gen5 (12 vCores) hw config. I'm approaching the limit of maximum storage (approx 3 TB), but since I read almost the entire database daily (cold start models only), I do not see many other options than increasing the storage size. Truncating parts of historical data is out of the question.

**Problem**

At 12 vCores, maximum storage is approx 3 TB, and increasing vCores to enable the approx 4 TB maximum storage size is not feasible in a $-perspective (especially since it is storage, not compute, that is the bottleneck). I have read a bit about the alternative services / tiers on the Azure platform, and see that Hyperscale could possibly solve my problem: I can keep vCores untouched and have up to 100 TB storage. A config with zero secondary replicas (other things equal) will end up in the same $-range as before (see "Backdrop"). I get the impression that secondary replicas (read only nodes) are central to the Hyperscale architecture, so I'm not sure if such an outlined setup with zero secondary replicas is abuse / misuse. E.g. would it give the same performance, or could I expect a performance hit (even with the same vCore config)? Will the primary read / write node basically resemble a non-Hyperscale node? Other aspects I should think about? Adding a secondary replica (or several) might be relevant in the future (e.g. in combination with decreasing vCores), but is $-wise not an option atm.

Microsoft states that "The capability to change from Hyperscale to another service tier is not supported" (really?), so I would like clarify this to avoid doing a semi manual data migration (and delta migration) and having two instances side-by-side if the shait hits the fan. Given the scope of such a reconfig and the forecasting system as a whole, I feel it is not feasible to do small / full scale testing in advance to get representtive benchmarks. If there is anything else I should think about (related or semi related), feel free to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hyperscale service tier is the newly added service tier in Azure SQL Database, it would be difficult to get the solid answer for your question.

It's true that it provides upto 100 TB database size, but the beauty is it will only charge for the capacity you use.

> The Hyperscale service tier removes many of the practical limits
> traditionally seen in cloud databases. Where most other databases are
> limited by the resources available in a single node, databases in the
> Hyperscale service tier have no such limits. With its flexible storage
> architecture, storage grows as needed. In fact, Hyperscale databases
> aren't created with a defined max size. A Hyperscale database grows as
> needed - and you're billed only for the capacity you use. For
> read-intensive workloads, the Hyperscale service tier provides rapid
> scale-out by provisioning additional replicas as needed for offloading
> read workloads.

You can have primary and secondary replica in Hyperscale service tier.

- Primary replica serves read and write operations
- Secondary replica provides read scale-out, high availability, and geo-replication

Secondary replicas are always read-only, and can be of three different types:

- High Availability replica (recommended)
- Named replica (in Preview, no guaranteed SLA)
- Geo-replica (in Preview, no guaranteed SLA)

You should consider Hyperscale service tier because:

- you need more size than 4 TB
- require fast vertical and horizontal compute scaling, high performance, instant backup, and fast database restore

**Note:** Users may adjust the total number of high-availability replicas from 0-4, depending on the need.

You can check the Hyperscale pricing model [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale#hyperscale-pricing-model).

Considering above points, Hyperscale is the good, if not the best, solution for your requirement.

These two links will definitely help you to take your decision. [Hyperscale service tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale), [Hyperscale secondary replicas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-replicas?tabs=tsql)

Comment: Thanks, @UtkarshPal-MT! I have already read a bit on the material you are referring to, but it does not give me complete confidence that this is a no brainer. So, in short, my TLDR question is this: _I get the impression that secondary replicas (read only nodes) are central to the Hyperscale architecture, so I’m not sure if such an outlined setup with zero secondary replicas is abuse / misuse. E.g. would it give the same performance, or could I expect a performance hit (even with the same vCore config and all other things equal)?_

Comment: Secondary replica is important if you need high availability. As it is mentioned in documents that **secondary replica provides read scale-out, high availability, and geo-replication.** It means, if in case the region where your primary database is physically located experienced any power outrage or natural disaster, your application will shift to the new secondary replica to keep your app running. Hence, setting up a secondary replica is important and recommended.

Comment: Also, the secondary replica doesn't mean increase in vCore. It simply replicates your primary database to another geographical location with same config for high availability.

Comment: I understand that the primary and secondary replica(s) will have the same hw config. I also understand that replication can provide horizontal scaling, _higher_ availability (99.95% instead of 99.9% according to the SLA) and geo-replication (in _preview_). I guess "more is more" (hence _"a secondary replica is important and recommended"_), but in my case $ is also a constraint. I mean... if a natural disaster etc hits my region, a geo-restore is totally acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the help btw, but I feel that my question is not fully answered yet: _I’m not sure if such an outlined setup with zero secondary replicas is abuse / misuse. E.g. would it give the same performance, or could I expect a performance hit (even with the same vCore config and all other things equal)?_

Comment: I can understand your concern. My suggestion is to post your question on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html) where product group team will directly reach to you and give the the better insights. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I actually got arranged a meeting with a MS representative (technical solution architect) last week to discuss my issue (and Hyperscale in general). In short, the conclusion was: _Oh, is it possible to use Hyperscale with zero secondary replicas? ...[a little later]... From my point of view, I can not see any red flags._ But maybe there is someone at MS Q&A a little more up to date -- thanks for the tip.

Comment: If anyone from the future finds this thread then it may also be worth checking if there were any helpful answers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609075/azure-sql-hyperscale-0-secondary-replicas.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the PM on the Azure SQL DB team. I see that UtkarshPal-MT already gave you extensive answer, so I'm chimining in on to complete the picture. Azure SQL DB Hyperscale offers different type of secondary replicas. The replicas that can help to get an higher SLA are named High-Availability replica. You can use 0 replicas without any issue. What will happen is that if the primary replicas for any reason is not available, we need to spin up a new (compute) replica from scratch (as there are no HA replica available) so that can take some time (minutes, usually) which means that your service will not be available that amount time. Having an HA replica, drastically diminish the time in which the database is not available.

You can read all the details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale-replicas?tabs=tsql

The SLA are defined here:

https://www.azure.cn/en-us/support/sla/sql-data/

Regarding the performances: unless you are specifically using secondary replicas also to offload read-only workload, you'll not have performance hit by not having an HA replica

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mauridb! I think a few minutes of db unavailability is acceptable. After all, 99.9% minimum availability is pretty decent. I have implemented retry logic to handle glitches of this size. Again, thank you so much for filling in more information.

Comment: If anyone from the future finds this thread then it may also be worth checking if there were any helpful answers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609075/azure-sql-hyperscale-0-secondary-replicas.html